# Meaning of (%.+)? in a regular expression

Tags: regex

What is the meaning of (%.+)? in a regular expression. I found it in a regular expression for IPv6 validation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing more than a `%` followed by at least one char, or nothing (https://www.debuggex.com/r/Fhim6RYIrGaujxCK).

Comment: [Check out](http://regex101.com/r/aR0vR5/1) the explanation on the right hand side

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: **SEE DEMO :** http://regex101.com/r/aR0vR5/2 That is the answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

The character `%` followed by a minimum of one other character except the line feed. The pattern is grouped and the group expected once or not at all.

- `()` - a group
- `.` - any character except line feed (see modifier/option `s`)
- `+` - pattern or character before has to exists once or many times
- `?` - pattern or character before can exists once or not